# Accessing a single character one by one?

Tags: mips

I am trying to access a single character one by one in MIPS.
Let's say the user enters 4624 or 45 — how would I access only 4 first, then 6 or 5, then 2, then 4?

Comment: what did you try? where are you stuck?

Comment: I got where it asks the user to enter in numbers as character but then how do i access them one by one

Comment: So like when you want to output the characters given by the user, I want to know how to get the character one by one.